# Не получается вывести результат. "Получить таблицу функции y(x) = 0,5x^2 – 7x при изменении x от –4 до 4 с шагом 0,5

Tags: excel, vba

недавно начал изучать VBA Excel и столкнулся с проблемой. Собственно, задача в заголовке. Вот моё решение, но отображает результат некорректно (только для x=4). Ах да, я знаю, что есть много фишек во всех языках программирования, но мне именно нужно решить отталкиваясь только от того, что изучил по программе.
Вот "решение"

```
Sub n6()
Dim x As Single, y As Single, i As Single
For x = (-4) To 4 Step 0.5
  For i = 1 To 10 Step 1
    Cells(i, 1) = x
    Cells(i, 2) = y
  Next i
  y = (0.5 * (x) ^ 2) - 7 * x
Next x
End Sub
```

Надеюсь, что кто-то ответит D: (p.s. да, я начинающий чайник, не бейте)

Comment: 1) Что это за странный внутренний цикл? Поясните логику его появления. 2) Вам не кажется, что сперва надо вычислить значение функции, а потом пихать его в ячейку, а не наоборот?

Comment: 1) Я местами всё стал менять, сбился, походу. 2) Звучит логично :D 3) Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub n6()
Dim x As Single, i As integer
For x = (-4) To 4 Step 0.5
    i=i+1
    Cells(i, 1) = x
    Cells(i, 2) = 0.5 * x ^ 2 - 7 * x
Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: Если уж функция, то так и просится в отдельную:`Cells(i, 2).Value = fY_(x)` `Function fY_(x As Single) As Single: fY_ = x * (0.5 * x - 7): End Function`

Comment: @vikttur Так-то да... но для домашки и так сойдёт.

Comment: Ну да. Написал для успокоения чувства прекрасного :)

Comment: Ну если перфекционировать - можно вообще две формулы в ячейки затолкать да растянуть...